# How to strip whitespace in Wintersmith preview output

Tags: wintersmith

Is there an easy way to remove all HTML whitespace from both preview and build output from Wintersmith, without writing a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Go to config.json and replace true to false here:

```
  "jade": {
    "pretty": false
  },
```